How to prevent the user from unselecting an option of a selectizeInput?
The default behavior for selectizeInput allows the user to click on a choice and delete it by hitting the Backspace or Delete key.
Is there any way of disabling that behavior?.
I have an app that allows users to add and remove groupings from the selectizeInput via 'add' and 'remove' action buttons. I don't want users to remove choices with the selectizeInput widget but rather by using the 'remove' action button.

Yes, use an onDelete event and return false:
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(
    inputId = 'selInput',
    label = 'No deletion',
    choices = state.name,
    multiple = TRUE,
    options = list(onDelete = I("function(value) {return false;}"))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, \(...) {
})

